# Como selecionar um texto dentro de uma string utilizando php

Tags: php, string, php-7

estou utilizando o PHP. Gostaria de selecionar um nome ou varios de acordo com o que for passado em uma string, e devolver essa seleçao em negrito. Ex:

Esse código já me retorna o nome, mas somente se for uma palavra ou palavras compostas que estejam juntas. nao onsegue selecionar letras na palavra  e nem retornar palavras ompostas separadas

```
   $selNomeGuerra= array(
              $nomedeguerra =>"<strong>$nomedeguerra</strong>"
            );



           $nomeNovo =  strtr($nomecompleto, $selNomeGuerra );





$nomecompleto = "FRANCISCO JOAO DA SILVA SOUZA";

$nomedo usuario = "J SOUZA";
```

GOSTARIA DE montar uma lista com o nome completo e o nome do usuário em negrito, esse foi m exemplo de nome, mas poderiam ser varias outras situações.

Entao retornaria a lista a assim: $nomeEditado = "FRANCISCO **J**OAO DA SILVA **SOUZA**"

Para ficar mais simples,  seria o que..

o usuario te passar um texto, composto ou nao, com caracteres isolados ou nao, como mostrado acima,  e retorno para ele toda a string com o que ele me passou, no meu caso busco no banco de dados,   retorno a string completa com  os caracteres selecionados em negrito.

O problema maior e selecionar ..

Comment: Não existe este "selecionar" em [tag:php], isto não é JavaScript! pelo que entendi, você precisaria de referências para retornar uma string formatada conformemente..

Comment: Por gentileza, adicione mais detalhes a sua pergunta, suas tentativas, esclareça o máximo possível! sugiro [**editar**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/521968/edit) ela, e adicionar esses critérios de um [mre] e [Como fazer uma boa pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)